# Expose variable values to client processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i'm developing a python util to manage a xRay experiment.

I have a 'server' process that manages the physical setup (vacuum pumps, detectors, control loops etc) and communicates with the hardware. I would like to write another library that could run on many 'client' computers, to allow users to read/write parameters on the server process.

In my mind i'd like to have the server share a python object (like a namedTuple) containing the parameters to the clients so that they are able to read/write the properties of that object.
Something like shared memory between threads but across the internet.

My question is, is there a easy way to accomplish this or do I have to implement my own communication protocol to share the data between the processes?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a database for this? That way you can also preserve the history of your experiments.